# Hidden Features of Sitecore CMS?

Tags: best-practices

This came to my mind after I saw the following question https://stackoverflow.com/q/9033/468718 and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features

We, Sitecore developers know the basics.

Some even mastered the areas like EXM, WFFM, Workflow, Powershell Extensions, etc.

But what are the most hidden features or tricks of Sitecore that people barely know it exists in Sitecore?

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `alt` + `r` shortcut. But to be honest, I don't think it's the best question here...

Comment: "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are hardly hidden, but maybe lesser known?

- F9 in Content Editor brings up the Site Publish dialog.
- Sitecore Rocks
- There are so many incredible pages in the Admin folder that can help you debug stuff. ShowConfig.aspx for your compiled Web.Config. Cache.aspx for cache tuning...
- Developer Center is still in Sitecore 8.x. You can get there by appending "/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=IDE" to your Sitecore path.